# How to alphabetical sort php while loop variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

i am selecting an id from a table and then by id getting name of all members by their ids. Now the problem is that , how to sort name ($uname) alphabetically?  It could be simple but i am stuck ..thanks for the help!! 
Code below -

```
$sql= mysql_query("Select DISTINCT(`Supervisor ID`) from `list`  ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   
     $id = $row['Supervisor ID'];
     $query = "SELECT `Name` from `list` WHERE `ID` = '$id'  ";
     $name = mysql_query($query);

     $username = mysql_fetch_array($name);

     $uname = $username['0'];


     $Supervisor .="<OPTION VALUE=\"$uname\">".$uname.'</option>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use This:-**

```
 $sql= mysql_query("Select DISTINCT(`Supervisor ID`) from `list`  ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   
     $id = $row['Supervisor ID'];
     $query = "SELECT `Name` from `list` WHERE `ID` = '$id'  ";
     $name = mysql_query($query);

     $username = mysql_fetch_array($name);
/* Sore name in to an new array */
     $uname[] = $username['0'];


}
```

**Sort your name Array Here Using**

```
sort()
```

[Click Here For Demo of Sort function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_sort_alpha)

```
 $user_names = sort($uname);
```

Create Option valus like this

```
foreach($uname as $name) {
$Supervisor .="<OPTION VALUE=\"$name\">".$name.'</option>';

}
```

Comment: Please Click True if answer is right. and also like the answer.

Comment: i can not vote up ur answer because i am new here and don't have reputation.

Comment: You can mark this Question as right. By just click True for this you don't need any reputition.

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY` clause is used for any kind of sorting from database.
So change your query in the loop like this:

```
$query = "SELECT `Name` from `list` WHERE `ID` = '$id' ORDER BY Name ASC  ";
```

For more information: [ORDER BY cluase](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Let me know for further help.

Comment: Thanks but i tried this already but it was not working. Is there any way that we can sort $uname variable?

Comment: Make one change in database & query will work. Go to database table column 'Name' and set it's 'Collation' as 'utf8_general_ci'. I think after this query has to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in single query, try this one..

```
$sql= mysql_query("Select DISTINCT Supervisor ID, Name from list ORDER BY Name ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   
     $uname = $row['1'];
     $Supervisor .="<OPTION VALUE=\"$uname\">".$uname.'</option>';

}
```

Comment: No actually, it will list all the names but i need only names corresponding to Supervisor Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Name` from `list` WHERE `ID` = '$id' order by `Name` ASC
```

use `order by` clause for ascending order and desc for descending order